# Rails share same partial when rendering array of STI objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb, single-table-inheritance, sti

My app implements Single Table Inheritance to address the logic of different types of user: `Admin, Client, Agent` with similar functionalities. All of them are written to the `User` table.

When rendering the `users#index` page I'd like for all of them to share the same partial, since I'm basically rendering the same.

```rb
#app/controllers/users_controller.rb
def index
  @users=User.all
end
```

```html
<!-- app/views/users/index.html.erb -->
<div class="row">
    <h2>
        Users
    </h2>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>User type</th>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Username</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <%=  render @users, as: :user, partial: 'users/user' %>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

```html
<!-- app/views/users/_user.html.erb -->
<tr>
    <th><%= user.class.name %></th>
    <th><%= user.id.to_s %></th>
    <th><%= user.username%></th>
</tr>
```

Whenever I try to go to the index page, I get an error of the kind `Missing partial admins/admin`.

I thought the line `<%= render @users, as: :user, partial: 'users/user' %>` would do, but it doesn't!

Comment: Have you tried setting an explicit collection option?

`<%= render partial: "users/user", collection: @users, as: :user %>`

Comment: wow, making it explicit indeed fixes it. I didn't even think about that option. Make it an answer and I will accept it, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= render partial: "users/user", collection: @users, as: :user %>
```

Try passing an explicit collection option.

Comment: Is there an opposite way to render different custom partials? <%= render partial: "info", collection: @users, as: :user %> and get partials users/_admin_info, users/_client_info etc.

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following instead:

```
 <tbody>
   <% @users.each do |user| %>
     <%= render :partial => 'users/user', :locals => {:user => user} %>
   <% end %>
 </tbody>
```

Comment: Good point. Although I think I will stick with the syntax I already have, and make `collection: @users` explicit, as @Baloo suggested.